How to best cite a series of equations?
This question kind of sits at the intersection of academia, math and latex stackexchange.
In my (mathematics) master's thesis, I am trying to cite a series of equtions like this (this may be a bit exaggerated):
"This means that
equation, (1)

where (may be more text here)
another equation (2)

and (may be more text here)
even more equations, (3)

so that (may be more text here)
final equation (4)"

This especially happens in "basics" sections.
All equations appear in a work, let's say [1].
Normally, when citing an equation, you would do
"This means that [1]
equation (1)"

if it is a single equation. But this is a series of equations with short text in-between. Do I have to make clear that each part is from [1] by adding the citation before each equation?

Give a label to each equation block (\label{eq:whatever}) so that each is assigned a reference number. Then at the beginning of this chunk of background info, something like

In [1] <author(s)> observed the following relations, collected here <verbatim/essentially verbatim/omit if you're actually making a minor reformulation and indicate that> in \Cref{label1,label2,...}. Summarizing his/her/their development of these equations, first note:...

if you're using CleverRef. If not, use \ref in whatever way you like to refer to the equations in your document.
If you prefer, you could also cite each equation referring to the numbering scheme of the original article. For attribution reasons, what's important is that you make clear that the authors of [1] came up with these equations, and that you are summarizing their development of them in your own words. If your short text blurbs are verbatim quotes, you should indicate that with quotation marks.
My experience is that mathematicians are not super picky about paraphrasing of interstitial wording between technical statements, but you should still include quotation marks and correct attribution for verbatim quotes.
